# Create a new column if one dataframe's row value is in another data frame's column and get that index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I may be overcomplicating this problem, however I can't seem to find a simple solution.

I have two DataFrame's. Let's call them df1 and df2. To keep things simple. Let's say df1 has one column called "Some Data" and df2 has two columns called "some data" and "other data".

Example:

df1

`Some Data
 "Lebron James 123"
 "Lebron James 234"`

df2

```
some data                        other data
"Lebron James 123 + other text"  "I want this in df1["New?"]"
"Michael Jordan"                 "Doesn't Matter"
```

So basically I want to create a new column in df1 called "New?". This new column (in df1) will say "New" if df1["Some data"] is in df2["Some other data"]. However, if there is no instance in df2["some data"], then I set the df1["New?"] to that specific row's value in df2["other data"].

Desired result after running:

df1

```
Some Data                         New?
"Lebron James 123"  "I want this in df1["New?"]"
"Lebron James 234"               "New"
```

So as you can see The New? column would include that specific row's value from the other data column. Lebron James 234 isn't anywhere in some data in df2 so it says new.

I am able to get it to say True or False using the `.isin()` method, however don't know how to grab the index of the other df and get the value from the other data column.

Thank you

EDIT:

From what I know will work

```
df["New?"] = df1["Some Data"].isin(df2["some data"])
```

Would render

df1["New?"]

```
True
False
```

So I want True to be the "I want this in df1["New?"]" and False to be New

Comment: What if a value in `df1` appears in more than one row in df2?

Comment: That doesn't make a difference to me. All I care about is if there is an instance of df1["Some Data"] in df2["some data"]. If there is than grab that row's value from df2["other data"]

Comment: Ok, so it gets easier... And just one more question ,what about your `df1`? Seems like you should have `+ other text` in first row, otherwise it wouldn't yield `True` in your output

Answer (score 1):

First create a regular expression by joining your `df1` series:

```
rgx = '|'.join(df1['some data'])
```

Now using `np.where`:

```
df1.assign(data=np.where(df2['some data'].str.match(rgx), df2['other data'], 'New'))
```

```
          some data                        data
0  Lebron James 123  I want this in df1["New?"]
1  Lebron James 234                         New
```

An example with mismatching shapes:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']})
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'a': ['aaaaa', 'bbbb', 'ffff', 'gggg', 'hhhh']})
```

```
rgx = '({})'.format('|'.join(df1.a))
m = df2.assign(flag=df2.a.str.extract(rgx))

df1.set_index('a').join(m.set_index('flag')).fillna('New').reset_index()
```

```
  index      a
0     a  aaaaa
1     b   bbbb
2     c    New
3     d    New
```

Comment: Similar solution to above, but I believe I would get same error. The actual data frames I use are much different in terms of their size (one has 13924 rows, and the other has about 2432). A simpler question for me to ask is how to get the index of that row of df2?

Comment: It is similar, however this answer does partial string matching, so it checks if a value from `df1['some data']` is *anywhere* in `df2['some data']`, not exact matching.  I'll update for differing shapes

Comment: @BeastlyBernardo added a solution with mismatched shapes

Answer (score 1):

Based on your info, seems like you need only a simple [`np.where`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.where.html) (if `dfs` have same length)

```
df1['New?'] = np.where(df1["Some Data"].isin(df2["some data"]), df2['other data'], 'New')

    Some Data                       New?
0   Lebron James 123 + other text   I want this in df1[New?"]"
1   Lebron James 234                New
```

---

For different length,

```
mask = df2["some data"].isin(df["Some Data"]).values
df.loc[mask,'New'] = df2.loc[mask, 'other data']

df.fillna('New')
```

*Explanation*

Basically you have a mask, and you use the same mask to filter both data frames. This yields the same number of results on both `dfs` given the descriptions, and you assign the filtered rows' "other data" values from `df2` to the same matching rows in `df` "some data"

Comment: Thanks for the help. Wish I had thought of np.where... I tried running this and am getting this error: `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (13294,) (2432,) () `

Comment: Also, how does it know which row number to grab from df2["other data"]? That's what I am confused about

Comment: Thank you... That is a long formula. Can you explain exactly what is doing? I'm having trouble following it.

Comment: @BeastlyBernardo Not sure I was clear, but have just edited. :)

Comment: Sorry... Still not exactly following. Why did you flip the isin() method? I don't care if df2 is in df1, only vice versa. Like I mentioned above, maybe a simpler question is how to grab the index (number) where the match is in df2. Because in my two DFs they are much different lengths. One has 13,000 rows, the other 2,000.

Comment: @BeastlyBernardo because when you flip it, you'll have `True` values for rows in your `df2`, which is the data frame that has `other data`. If you do the other way around, you'll have rows in `df` that have `True` if value in `some data` is in `df2` `some data`. But then this doesn't help to get `other data` from df2

Comment: Hmm... well that code makes sense I guess but wasn't producing results I needed. Was getting NaN for everything. So back to this the index question. How would I go about grabbing the row number (index) of the df2 where there is a match i.e when `df["Some Data"].isin(df2["some data"])` is True. So I need to somehow do df2.index of the above code... Does that make sense?